# Android Click button behind another button

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, gesturedetector

I have 6 Buttons (green) that open apps. On top of this buttons there is another button which I use for swipe listener.

If no swipe is detected (click) I want to click green buttons else perform swipe action triggered by red button.

[image: img1]

here is my TouchListener taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {}
    public void onSwipeLeft() {}
    public void onSwipeTop() {}
    public void onSwipeBottom() {}
    public void onTap() {}
}
```

This is where I initialize listener.

```
Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_hex_over);
final Context c = context;

ok.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getBaseContext()) {
    public void onSwipeTop() {}
    public void onSwipeBottom() {}
    public void onTap() {}
});
```

Swipe works but cannot click buttons.

Comment: where is your onClickListener ?

Comment: You don't need the red button for a `GestureListener`. A simple layout does the job aswell.

Comment: @MuratK. But I need a listener on whole surface and not only buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `GridView` with fixed 3x3 view.
There you can set swipe gesture on your `GridView` like

```
grid.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(mContext)
        {

            public void onSwipeRight()
            {

            }

            public void onSwipeLeft()
            {

            }

        });
```

and also you can set

```
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View cell, int position, long id)
                {
                }

            });
```

For future you can add more Buttons with very less coding.

Comment: Thanks I try it as soon as I get to it. Green buttons are already in GridView so I will just need to put listener on in.

Comment: @CBeTJlu4ok if this helps you in your requirement you can accept the answer