# GridView.setOnItemClickListener triggers whole row

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, android-gridview

I have a grid view 3x3. Inside this grid I have `ImageView`s.

I set up `OnItemClickListener` but when I click on the `ImageView` only the first one is pressed in a row no matter which column I am pressing. Also I can be pressing outside the `ImageView` (empty space) but still first `ImageView` on that row is pressed.

XML

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

MainActivity

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.test);
gridview.setAdapter(new HexAdapter(getBaseContext()));
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.e("gridView", "hallo" + position);
    }
});
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class HexAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public HexAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return (Object) mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo,
        R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo,
        R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo,
    };
}
```

R.drawable.logo is just a random image a chose.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20191914/how-to-add-gridview-setonitemclicklistener

Comment: @NovoLucas I already red that one. unfortunately I need to make a onItemClickListener. No clickListener inside adapter.

Comment: @NovoLucas see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343681/android-click-button-behind-another-button if you want to know more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced this problem and the solution I came up with is simple:

In your adapter give an unique TAG to each view

```
view.setTag(id); //example
```

And on ItemClickListener just match the tags for each view and you will be sure this will never happen:

```
if(view.getTag().equals(id))
    doStuff();
if(view.getTag().equals(otherId))
    doOtherStuff();
```

And so on.

Here is an example:

**Adapter**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ImageView imageView;
    CustomTextView textView;
    LinearLayout main_grl;

    if (v == null) {
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.professions_gridview_item,parent,false);
    }

    main_grl = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.main_grl);
    main_grl.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.ps_background_selector));
    imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    textView = (CustomTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    imageView.setImageResource(ApplicationConstants.finalListIV[position]);
    textView.setText(ApplicationConstants.finalListTV[position]);
    v.setTag(ApplicationConstants.finalListTV[position]);

    return v;
}
```

**Activity**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if((Integer) view.getTag() == someTag){
        //doStuff
    } else if((Integer) view.getTag() == otherTag){
        //doOtherStuff
    } else{
        //andSomeOther
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha what a coincidence, I had a problem with tags today, I wanted to use more than one tag. Thanks for this.

Comment: Unfortunatley it does not do. Problem is that no matter the column first button is pressed in row, so it always returns same tag for a row

Comment: @Ricardo sorry no problem there but I just checked added them. Nothing changed. Since I have return mThumbIds.length; it still works

Comment: here is a full working example code on the edited post

Comment: I upovted for help but I found the problem is my onTouchListener that I put on gridView. without it it works fine

Comment: Glad it helped.